# How to add zip dependency(has 50+ jars) to classpath to compile using pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have zip dependency from repository. It has 50+ jars in it. I am able to download it and unpack it. Now I want to add these jars to classpath for compilation. these jars not getting added to classpath, so build is failing with compiler errors. I need these jars only for compilation(not in war).
I spent two days didn't satisfacoty solution(don't want to use system scope, local repository). I this link [How to put maven zip dependency on classpath for Java tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176602/how-to-put-maven-zip-dependency-on-classpath-for-java-tests). it didn't work because may be its for test not for compile. I need same thing for compile.

Comment: What are these dependencies?  Would it be possible to obtain them from a place such as the Maven Central Repository?  If so, then you could just include them in your POM.  If they are custom JARs, then you will have to install them into a repo somewhere.

Comment: zip file comes from Repo central. It has jars. I don't know what are all those jars and their artifactids etc. previously its ant build, now I am converting it into maven project. I want to know is there any way to add  zip as dependency then maven will takecare of unzip and adding jars too the classpath? or atleast how to add [unpacked] jars to compiler classpath?

Comment: Did you try maven's fileSet?